# Calculate Max of Sum Product of D3 array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm reading a csv file, and need to compute two figures from this data using D3.js or normal JavaScript:

This might be able to be done in one step, but I've broken it down for the purposes of explanation:

Once my data is read in, I need to iterate through each of the columns, labelled "one" to "ten" 
(the length of this data is an unknown length, so it might go up to twelve or twenty),

...each time multiplying each column which comes after "multiplier" by variable called "multiplier" 
(in the data, I gave it arbitrary values of 1.5, 1, 0,5 to make reading visually clearer).

This gives a new grid of figures from which a maximum score and minimum score of each of these new figures must be calculated for each ID from 1 to n. So each ID will have a max and minimum.  I need to know the maximum and minimum of these new scores across the entire data returned as variables.

The data is read in:

`d3.csv("data.csv", function(csv) {
  var mydata = bars
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(csv)
  .enter()`};

The example data appears as:

ID,total,mutiplier,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten
1,16500,1.5,0.362,0.37,0.1,0.101,0.035,0.362,0.37,0.1,0.101,0.035
2,61000,1,0.426,0.382,0.115,0.084,0.053,0.426,0.382,0.115,0.084,0.053
3,48700,1.5,0.156,0.531,0.195,0.399,0.14,0.156,0.149,0.106,0.399,0.14
4,33000,0.5,0.462,0.409,0.149,0.106,0.149,0.106,0.085,0.1,0.106,0.051
5,8000,0.5,0.327,0.316,0.085,0.1,0.085,0.1,0.057,0.245,0.1,0.057
6,12760,1,0.149,0.195,0.057,0.245,0.057,0.245,0.119,0.114,0.245,0.08

This original data cannot be replaced as I reference it later.

So from this data, after iterating through all columns, and taking the max and min from each over the whole data --- the minimum is 0.003535 and the maximum is 3.8875575

...and I need the function to return a var min and var max for next calculation.

Hope someone out there can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can load your data as a text, and latter use [`d3.csv.parseRows`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parseRows) to parse your CSV as an array of arrays. So just take the slice, ignoring the first 3 columns.

```
d3.text('data.csv', function(text)
{
  var rows = d3.csv.parseRows(text, function(row, index)
  {
    // skip header, coerce to Number values
    if(index > 0)
    {
      return row.map(Number);
    }
  });
  var extent = rows.reduce(function(result, row)
  {
    return d3.extent(result.concat(row.slice(3).map(function(value)
    {
      return value * row[2];
    })));
  }, [NaN, NaN]);
  var min = extent[0];
  var max = extent[1];
});
```

Other way if array of objects is more convenient structure for later plotting, you can do the following.

```
var nonMeasureColumns = {'ID': 0, 'total': 0, 'multiplier': 0};
d3.csv('data.csv')
  .row(function(row)
  {
    for(var key in row)
    {
      row[key] = Number(row[key]);
    }
    return row;
  })
  .get(function(error, rows)
  {
    var extent = rows.reduce(function(result, row)
    {
      return d3.extent(result.concat(d3.map(row).entries()
        .filter(function(entry)
        {
          return !(entry.key in nonMeasureColumns);
        })
        .map(function(entry)
        {
          return entry.value * row['multiplier'];
        })
      ));
    }, [NaN, NaN]);
    var min = extent[0];
    var max = extent[1];
  });
```